# partialRight in Lodash seems to do nothing

Tags: javascript, lodash

(I couldn't find an [open](https://lodash.slack.com/) Lodash Slack channel, that's why I'm posting here.)

Could you please tell me why the `partialRight` in this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/myqt9nrx/5/) seems to do nothing? The `correctRenameKeys` function correctly renames the key in the supplied `object`, but the `wrongRenameKeys` function - which should do exactly the same - doesn't.

Please open the JavaScript console in your browser to see logs when running the fiddle. I tested it in Chrome.

```js
    const renameKeysOfOneObject = (object, keyMappings) => {
      return _.reduce(object, function(result, value, key) {
        key = keyMappings[key] || key;
        result[key] = value;
        return result;
      }, {});
    };

    const correctRenameKeys = (objects, keyMappings) => {
        const keysRenamer = object => renameKeysOfOneObject(object, keyMappings);
        return _.map(objects, keysRenamer);
    };

    const wrongRenameKeys = (objects, keyMappings) => {
        const keysRenamer = _.partialRight(renameKeysOfOneObject, keyMappings);
        return _.map(objects, keysRenamer);
    };

    const object = {keyToBeRenamed: 'someValue'};
    const objects = [object];
    const keyMapping = {keyToBeRenamed: 'newKeyName'};

    const correctlyRenamed = correctRenameKeys(objects, keyMapping);
    const wronglyRenamed = wrongRenameKeys(objects, keyMapping);

    console.assert(_.isEqual(correctlyRenamed, wronglyRenamed), 
                   "The two objects should be equal. " + 
                   "The 'keyToBeRenamed' key should have been renamed to 'newKeyName'.");
    console.log(correctlyRenamed);
    console.log(wronglyRenamed);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.4/lodash.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are two supporting statements from the lodash documentation that can answer your question:

[`lodash#partialRight`](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.4#partialRight)

> This method is like _.partial except that partially applied arguments
>   are appended to the **arguments** it receives.

[`lodash#map`](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.4#map)

> Creates an array of values by running each element in collection thru
>   iteratee. The iteratee is invoked with three **arguments**: (value,
>   index|key, collection).

Notice that there are three arguments passed in a `lodash#map` iteratee, and since `keyRenamer` is passed as it's iteratee, then we can conclude that the invocation signature would look like this:

```
keyRenamer(value, index, collection, keyMappings);
```

If you really want to achieve the effect of having the second argument of the function `renameKeysOfOneObject` to be partially applied then use [`lodash#partial`](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.4#partial).

```
const wrongRenameKeys = (objects, keyMappings) => {
    const keysRenamer = _.partial(renameKeysOfOneObject, _, keyMappings);
    return _.map(objects, keysRenamer);
};
```

```js
const renameKeysOfOneObject = (object, keyMappings) => {
      return _.reduce(object, function(result, value, key) {
        key = keyMappings[key] || key;
        result[key] = value;
        return result;
      }, {});
    };

    const correctRenameKeys = (objects, keyMappings) => {
        const keysRenamer = object => renameKeysOfOneObject(object, keyMappings);
        return _.map(objects, keysRenamer);
    };

    const wrongRenameKeys = (objects, keyMappings) => {
        const keysRenamer = _.partial(renameKeysOfOneObject, _, keyMappings);
        return _.map(objects, keysRenamer);
    };

    const object = {keyToBeRenamed: 'someValue'};
    const objects = [object];
    const keyMapping = {keyToBeRenamed: 'newKeyName'};

    const correctlyRenamed = correctRenameKeys(objects, keyMapping);
    const wronglyRenamed = wrongRenameKeys(objects, keyMapping);

    console.assert(_.isEqual(correctlyRenamed, wronglyRenamed), 
                   "The two objects should be equal. " + 
                   "The 'keyToBeRenamed' key should have been renamed to 'newKeyName'.");
    console.log(correctlyRenamed);
    console.log(wronglyRenamed);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper{min-height:100%;top:0}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.4/lodash.min.js"></script>
```